# Boot.mount fails after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, lvm

This problem has happened across many of our servers that were upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04. The common configuration is that root is an LVM, and either there is a /boot partition, or a /boot and /boot/efi partition. For example:

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME                         FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                   
├─sda1                       vfat              C45F-2000                         /boot/efi     
├─sda2                       ext2              a906fd59-cb58-4c94-8560-5d426e4   /boot
└─sda3                       LVM2_member       1P3Rxv-VZMx-gcs9-PlxM-DCI8-kIqr
  ├─node--007--vg-root       ext4              316678d5-aaaf-43bd-bac6-cc3aeb1   /
  ├─node--007--vg-swap_1     swap              0724b0b0-9f2d-42aa-bbe2-7b8aa31   [SWAP]
  ├─node--007--vg--na      ext4              7d42481b-f7fb-4ac6-9cf5-5df3ca17   /cache/na
  ├─node--007--vg-c        ext4              e38d96f8-6afb-4d2c-94cc-28a02e90   /cache/c
  └─node--007--vg-t        ext4              44559b67-869e-4454-b792-792c1a16   /cache/d
```

The with kernel debug logging I always see this kind of logging about timing out waiting for the device

```
Mar 30 16:14:22 ns1 systemd-udevd[539]: seq 3206 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda' is taking a long time
Mar 30 16:14:22 ns1 systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Got notification message from PID 539 (WATCHDOG=1)
Mar 30 16:14:50 ns1 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a906fd59\x2dcb58\x2d4c94\x2d8560\x2d5d426e4.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a906fd59\x2dcb58\x2d4
Mar 30 16:14:50 ns1 systemd-journald[501]: Forwarding to syslog missed 70 messages.
Mar 30 16:14:50 ns1 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a906fd59\x2dcb58\x2d4c94\x2d8560\x2d5d426e4.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a906fd59\x2dcb58\x2d4
Mar 30 16:14:50 ns1 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a906fd59\x2dcb58\x2d4c94\x2d8560\x2d5d426e4.device.
Mar 30 16:14:50 ns1 systemd[1]: boot.mount: Job boot.mount/start finished, result=dependency
Mar 30 16:14:50 ns1 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot.
```

The swap and LVMs are mounted by this point. Emergency mode is entered, and pressing control-D continues the boot and then all is good.

If  I tar all the files under /boot, umount /boot and /boot/efi and then untar them, change the fstab, update the initramfs, and reboot without those partitions then the node boots.

I have noticed that the log saying that /dev/sda is plugged does not happen before the emergency mode is entered, even though the lvms are mounted successfully. After pressing control-D to continue the boot the log happens, and everything including sda2 mounts just fine.

```
Mar 30 16:15:33 ns1 systemd[1]: dev-sda.device: Changed dead -> plugged
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around I turned on the very handy debug logging in /etc/udev/udev.conf, and updated my initramfs.

```
$ cat /etc/udev/udev.conf 
# see udev.conf(5) for details
#
# udevd is started in the initramfs, so when this file is modified the
# initramfs should be rebuilt.

#udev_log="info"
#event_timeout=300
udev_log="debug"
```

This helped me identify the problem. There were thousands of 'curls' happening early in the boot, and those were from a udev rule that was acting on adding and removing of 'sd*' devices. I commented out those rule actions and now the system boots!  The logs are viewable with journalctl -b.